# Building Spring standalone application using Autowired annotation

Tags: spring, autowired

I'm learning about Spring and watched some tutorials to understand the concept, but I couldn't find any example related to my question so I'm not even sure if it is supposed to work like that or maybe I did not understand the concept at all

Is it possible to build a simple Java SE project using the spring autowiring using  @Autowire annotation without having to set beans and stuff in a spring.xml?

Like just defining some composed classes, with have some @Autowired fields defined as @Component and be good to go?

Here is soem code with the general idea:

Framework.java

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class Framework {

    private String insertTest;

}
```

SpringTest.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private Framework testeFramework;

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringTest tester = new SpringTest();
        tester.getTesteFramework().setInsertTest("dummy");

        System.out.println(tester.getTesteFramework().getInsertTest());

    }

}
```

As of now, I'm getting NullPointException from the tester.getTesteFramework() instruction.

Could you explain what is missing or how to make it work?
Code examples would be much apreciated ^^

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SpringTest tester = new SpringTest();
```

This cannot work because by calling the constructor yourself, it is no longer a Spring managed bean and thus not eligible for dependency injection. On top of that, in no way have you marked `SpringTest` as being a Spring managed bean. Any class that makes use of `@Autowired` must live inside the Spring container.

To make this work you would need to add the `@Component` annotation to `SpringTest`, and then do something like `ApplicationContext.getBean(SpringTest.class)` in your main method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

So do I still need a spring.xml file to configure the beans?
Is there a way to instanciate the application context?

Comment: There are multiple ways to configure the Spring container, xml is not required. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans